# Is it possible to solve this?

Tags: c++, c, puzzle

Recently I encountered this puzzle :

```
 int main(){
     int arr[7];
     int b,c,d,a;
     a=4;
     printf("%d",arr[?]);
   return 0;
}
```

The question is to **Replace "?" with a integer so that output is 4.** I am not sure but I don't think this is solvable in a standard way ?! (Not invoking Undefined Behavior or depending on implementation) If NO, then I am very interested in knowing how ?

**Edit**:This task is taken from [here](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ARR/), I tried to solve with 10, but sadly it's not the answer the problem setter wants.However, I [solved](https://www.spoj.pl/status/ARR,debanjan/) it using some pretested implementation dependent mumbo-jumbo,but I really have no explanation for how it really works!

Here is the answer : [SPOILER](http://ideone.com/C63Ua),You are welcome to explain it

Comment: There is no way to guarantee the output is four, with those restrictions. If you allow the "?" to be anything, then you can replace it with `0] = 4, arr[0`.

Comment: @SLaks : I have updated it as a spoiler.

Comment: I knew that ... it's giving correct in only my system and certain other system with g++ (as confirmed by some of my friends).You could see that here http://www.spoj.pl/ranks/ARR/,However,I already mentioned I have no explanation for this.

Comment: Stupid question.

Comment: There is no solution without invoking **UB**. Adding any integer outside the range 0-7 to `arr` invokes UB for the pointer addition, and since the array is uninitialized, even if `?` is in the range 0-7, accessing the uninitialized object invokes UB.

Comment: "I strictly despise problem like this which solely depends on implementation."  **<--- THIS**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming there is no answer that conforms to the standard, could you use an operation (obviously not an integer) like arr[&a-arr]?

Edit: Made cleaner thanks to Ben and others in the comments.

Comment: I think you might need some parentheses there, because subtracting a pointer from 0 is undefined, but that's quite elegant.

Comment: Not quite there, because the values in brackets are multiplied by sizeof(int)... but the idea's sound were it not for the restriction that `?` be an integer constant.

Comment: @Tony, it doesn't say that the answer must be an integer literal, it only says it must be an integer.  Difference between two pointers IS an integer.  So is negation of an integer.  Also, difference between two pointers divides by `sizeof (int)`, which cancels out the multiplication you mentioned.  So ? = `-(arr-&a)` is correct.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, and after a bottle of corona and a bottle of Smithwick's I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. Suggestions?

Comment: @Ben: great point re integer versus integer literal.  I didn't really look at the contents of the expression... another good call on the pointer difference.  Amusing that I considered and discounted this very approach :-).

Comment: when using gcc the [?] = [-1], visual studio cl the [?] = [8]

Comment: @emailhy: if you consider your entire computer memory, there are doubtless a lot of memory locations that contain "4", and so what you say may well be true, but it's likely a coincidence, whereas the values 10, and the expression Sam suggests, are pretty and totally reliable respectively

Comment: Accepted mainly because of Ben Voigt comments :)

Answer (score 15):

In most implementations, `arr[10]` (or 7) will be 4, since the locals will be laid out sequentially.

However, this is neither defined nor standard, and *must not* be relied on.

Comment: Well, could you please explain what do you meant by `since the locals will be laid out sequentially` ?

Comment: arr[7] takes up 7 bytes, then _int b_ will be in the next byte, __int c__ in the next byte... accessing arr[10] would be skipping out of the array and into the neighboring memory, which is these newly declared ints (hopefully)

Comment: This is only true if you have optimisation turned off! Even low levels of optimisation  will drop b c and d as they are never used. Higher levels of optimisation may move varaible a to the begining of the stack as it is used first (ordering variables in the order they are used can increase cache hits and "free" chache loads).

Comment: arr[7] had better take more than 7 bytes, in a conforming implementation, because the range of an octet is only -128 to 127, not enough for `int`.

Comment: If the variables are allocated on the stack as the compiler encounters them, then `a` could well be *below* `arr` in memory, since stacks often grow downwards - ie. `a` may be aliased with `arr[-4]` instead (or indeed, a range of unlimited other possibilities).

Comment: @caf: limited by address space, I hope

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I was more referring to possibilities like `b`, `c` and `d` being eliminated since they are never referenced, or `a` being assigned to a register rather than a memory location since its address is never taken.

Comment: -1 in "most implementations" the stack grows downwards, b, c, d and a will be before arr in memory.

Comment: Without reading the spoiler, I'd say -1 would do the trick (which is why they put a last in the list).

Comment: @JeremyP: In most implementations, the compiler adds together the size of all locals, and adjusts the stack pointer **once**, creating a single large block.  How the local variables are arranged inside that block varies wildly, but often the compiler will minimize padding by grouping variables with similar alignment requirements together (that doesn't affect this question, where all the variables are the same type).  The compiler may also adjust the stack pointer by a variable offset if, e.g. it wants to guarantee 16-byte alignment for SSE and MMX data.  None of this is standard, just common.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect on some systems 10 would do the trick (depending on alignment and padding, and the size of `int`), but that IS undefined behavior. I can't see any standard way to do what's asked.

Comment: Only if the stack grows upwards.

Answer (score 1):

on http://ideone.com:

```
#include "stdio.h" 
int main(){
     int arr[7];
     int b,c,d,a;
     a=4;
     printf("%p %p %d %d",arr, &a, arr - &a, arr[7]);
   return 0;
}

0xbfa95918 0xbfa95934 -7 4
```

optimizer removes b,c,d hence a right at 7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a trick question, maybe there's a 4 but it doesn't exist in the array (so maybe some strange index will give you a 4 for an interesting reason).

Comment: Yes the index is really strange !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a portable answer is possible if `?` needs to be replaced by an integer; but a portable solution may be possible if an expression is allowed; using the fact that `a [i] == i [a]`.

```
 printf("%d",arr[(unsigned long) ((a & (1 << ((sizeof (int) - 1) * CHAR_BIT))) ?
                                 /* Big Endian */
                                 memset (calloc ((unsigned long) arr + sizeof (int), 1),
                                         4, (unsigned long) arr + 1)
                                 :
                                 /* Small Endian*/
                                 memset (memset (malloc ((unsigned long) arr + sizeof (int)),
                                                 4, (unsigned long) arr + sizeof (int)),
                                         0,
                                         (unsigned long) arr + sizeof (int) - 1)
                                 )]);
```

You'd need a huge amount of RAM to work; and I can't test the correctness for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat 4130250.c \
> && echo -------- \
> && sed -e 's/\?/arr[0] = 4, 0/' 4130250.c | gcc -xc - \
> && ./a.out
int main(){
int arr[7],b,c,d,a;
a=4;
printf("%d\n", arr[?]);
return 0;
}
--------
<stdin>: In function `main`:
<stdin>:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function `printf`
4
```

Explanation of the command line :-)

`cat 4130250.c`: output the contents of the "program"
`echo --------`: output a separator
`sed ...`: replace the "?" with "arr[0] = 4, 0" and write to standard output
`| gcc -xc -`: compile C from standard input (the output of the previous sed)
`./a.out`: run the produced binary